# python: Quadratic correlation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

My question is the following. Assuming I have these two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,5,5,4,3,2,1])
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

Is there a way to calculate some kind of "quadtratic correlation coefficient" (Quadratic regression: y=A+Bx+Cx2) between them? Something like here is done: http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/14059932254941

Furthermore if that would be possible, is it also possible to calculate correlation coefficients to other polynomial/exponential functions?

Best regards!

Comment: There is no such thing as "quadratic correlation coefficient", it's just quadratic regression. In NumPy there is [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) for least-squares polynomial regression and SciPy has [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for general function fitting, for example. The correlation coefficient could be computed with [`np.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)

Comment: But there has to be a way to calculate a coefficient how good the data fits to linear, quadtratic..and so on function?

Comment: The correlation coefficient measures whether `x` changes when `y` changes. The goodness of each particular method can be measured in different ways, e.g. mean squared error if it's a function, likelihood if it's a statistical model, etc.

Comment: Of course np.corrcoef will lead to a low coefficient because it is linear

Comment: @jdehesa Ok If I understand you right, I would do a poly or curvefit to get a function from the data and thean do a mean squared error between this function and a quadtratic function for example? How would this look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have some data (I'm going to change the values because you have repeated X values with different Y):

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y1 = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 5, 2])
```

You can find different polynomial fits with [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
fit1 = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 1)  # linear
fit2 = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 2)  # quadratic
fit3 = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 3)  # cubic
```

You can check how good each of these is by evaluating the resulting polynomials with [`np.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html):

```
v1 = np.polyval(fit1, x1)
v2 = np.polyval(fit2, x1)
v3 = np.polyval(fit3, x1)
```

These look like this:

[image: Polynomial fits]

You can check numerically how well each of these fit for example calculating the [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error):

```
mse1 = np.mean(np.square(y1 - v1))  # 3.240
mse2 = np.mean(np.square(y1 - v2))  # 0.734
mse3 = np.mean(np.square(y1 - v3))  # 0.727
```

Now, besides this, you can look at correlation. There are actually several kinds of [correlation coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient). NumPy implements the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) in [`np.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html):

```
np.corrcoef(x1, y1)
# [[ 1.        ,  0.27578314],
#  [ 0.27578314,  1.        ]]
```

This coefficient measures linear correlation, so it will not work well with non-linear relationships. However, non-linear correlation is in general a much more complicated topic (and [still under research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4539721/)). You can look into some of the other correlation coefficients or investigate other techniques, but note that this will only tell you if there *exists* some correlation, it will not tell you whether you will be able to construct a model exploiting the correlation.

Comment: Is it also possible to do the same for a gaussian fit? I mean the mean squared error?

Comment: Same as you have [least-squares estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) for function fitting (minimize MSE), you have methods for probability distributions. For example, in Bayesian statistics you have [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), [maximum a posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) and [Bayes estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator), each is used to fit a model according to some statistical "quality measure".